# Автоматизация смены пароля внутри Docker-контейнера

Tags: bash, docker, password

Мне нужно при помощи bash-скрипта:

1. Запустить контейнер
2. Сгенерировать пароль
3. Зайти в контейнер
4. Выполнить команду 'cd /'
5. Сменить пароль при помощи htpasswd

Я пробовал так:

```
docker restart c1
a = date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 ; echo
docker exec -u 0 -it c1 bash 'echo cd /'
htpasswd user.passwd webdav a
```

И так:

```
docker restart c1
docker exec -u 0 -it c1 bash
cd /
a = date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 ; echo
htpasswd user.passwd webdav a
```

При первом варианте получаю:

> bash: echo cd /: No such file or directory

При втором он входит в контейнер и ничего не делает

Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: вы можете попытаться сформировать подобную команду: `docker exec -u 0 -it c1 bash -c "cd / && <создание пароля> && htpasswd <изменение пароля>"`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Ваш пример немного помог, но не получается менять пароль автоматом. Контейнер перезапускается, пароль генерируется, но последний этап не получается реализовать
`docker exec -u 0 -it c1 bash -c "cd / && pass=C tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 13 ; echo && htpasswd -i user.passwd $pass"`